# Error expected declaration en c

Tags: struct

Al compilar me suelta el error "expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘cliente’, en las lineas 25 a la 29, tengo que hacer una serie de registros; al parecer el error esta en la declaracion que tambien suelta warnings al respecto; corte algunas funciones que no me deja subir tanto codigo

```
 struct Clientes
    {
        char nombre[10];
        char apellido[10];
        int habitacion;
        char fecha[10];
        int dias;
        char formaPago[10];
        char cafeteria[2];
        float costo;
    }cliente;


int Hotel();
void Ingresar(cliente *reg, int *cont);
void DatosResidente(cliente * reg, int *cont);
void Actualizar(cliente * reg, int cont);
void Borrar(cliente * reg, int cont);
void Bucar(cliente * reg, int *cont);


int main()
{
        

}
int Hotel()
{
    
}
void Ingresar(cliente * reg, int *cont)
{


}
void Actualizar(cliente * reg, int cont){
}
void Borrar(cliente * reg, int *cont){
}
void Buscar(cliente * reg, int cont){
}
void DatosResidente(cliente * reg, int cont)
{
}
    
        

'''
```

Comment: De la forma en que está, `cliente` es una variable con tipo `struct Clientes` y no un tipo. Si lo que quieres es que sea un nuevo nombre para `struct Clientes` tendrias que usar typedef: `typedef struct Clientes { char nombre[10]; } cliente;`

Comment: ahh gracias, se me paso eso